# An invalid request was sent to the Sitecore layout service

Tags: sitecore

I have a Sitecore 10.3 XP installation and a Visual Studio solution with Helix, where we are implementing components. My local sitecore CM installation is running perfectly fine. However, when I am trying to run my VS solution, I am getting the error

> An invalid request was sent to the Sitecore layout service.

We are using JSS headless implementation and even though everything is correctly installed and verified, I have an access denied message from the JSS API key:
[https://unify-103-xp-sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={key}&sc_site={website-name}](https://unify-103-xp-sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=%7Bkey%7D&sc_site=%7Bwebsite-name%7D)
Any suggestion/direction will be highly appreciated.

I tested the GraphQL API and it is working fine.
I have re-installed JSS headless implementation and by looking at the folder structure it looked okay.
I verified that in the web database the key is same as in the master one.
I verified that the publishing is done.

Somehow I am getting the "access denied" for the JSS headless API key.